# Error in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, http

I'm currently using MongoDB. I'm trying to access the admin page provided by MongoDB on my browser but getting this error:

> It looks like you are trying to access MongoDB over HTTP on the native driver port.

Comment: which [`port`](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-status-interface) did you try connecting to?

Comment: `27017` is the port which i am trying to access

Comment: Admin page same like as xampp

Comment: Did you try `28017` as specified in the [`docs`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/)? `27017` is taken up by the `mongod` and `mongos` instances.

Comment: The default port is `21017` (mentioned in the docs)on which i am getting this error.

Comment: How can we access the admin ui of mongo db ?

Answer (score 1):

From [MongoDB Docs](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/)

> 27017  The default port for mongod and mongos instances. You can change this port with port or --port.

and you are looking for this:

> 28017  The default port for the web status page. The web status page is always accessible at a port number that is 1000 greater than the port determined by port.

Port `27017` is used to access database data with your favourite MongoDB client application (Robomongo, for example). And port `28017` is used to access web status page you are looking for. So, try this in your browser:

> http://localhost:28017/